# Incluir archivos ocultos en un tar

Tags: linux, unix

Necesito un comando que pueda incluir archivos ocultos dentro de un tar.gz Hasta ahora utilizo

```
$ tar -zcvf respaldo.tar.gz /var/www/sitio.com/
```

Pero esto no me almacena los archivos ocultos como **.htaccess** ¿Cómo puedo incluir estos archivos en un comando similar?

Comment: Es raro que no te funcione, ¿en qué consola trabajas (bash, shell...)? ¿Y sistema operativo? Si solamente tienes un fichero oculto puedes decir directamente `tar -zcvf respaldo.tar.gz /var/www/sitio.com/ /var/www/sitio.com/.htaccess`. Si no, siempre puedes usar `/var/www/sitio.com/{.,}*` para que se expanda todo.

Answer (score 1):

Si se graban los ficheros ocultos !!!

Ejemplo:
Creo carpeta de prueba, me situo dentro y creo 2 ficheros (visible y oculto):

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/prueba
$ cd /tmp/prueba
$ touch fichero_normal .fichero.oculto
$ ls
fichero_normal

luisgulo@mitnick:/tmp/prueba$ ls -la
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 luisgulo tic-servinf  4096 nov 30 12:34 .
drwxrwxrwt 18 root     root        65536 nov 30 12:34 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 usuario grupo     0 nov 30 12:34 fichero_normal
-rw-r--r--  1 usuario grupo     0 nov 30 12:34 .fichero.oculto
```

Me situo antes del directorio a salvar y realizo un tar del mismo..
Puedes ver en la salida de la ejecución que SI se estan almacenando los fichero ocultos

```
$ cd ..
$ tar cvfp prueba.tar prueba
prueba/
prueba/.fichero.oculto
prueba/fichero_normal
```

Comment: Prueba a realizar el "tar" de la carpeta que contiene los ficheros en vez de desde dentro de la carpeta.... y si necesitas excluir algun fichero o ruta indicalo con --exclude=patron

Answer (score 0):

El comando find puede servir para esto.  Pon atención al "+" al final, no lo debes quitar.

```
find . -type f -exec tar zcvf test.tar.gz ./ +
```

En el anterior ejemplo estás comprimiendo el directorio actual incluyendo todos sus subdirectorios, cuyo resultado será almacenado en el archivo comprimido test.tar.gz.  Si sólo deseas comprimir el contenido del actual directorio sin sus subdirectorios, utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar zcvf test.tar.gz ./ +
```